# Проблемы с плавным перемещением TSplitter.

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты! Вероятно, моя проблема Вам покажется очень глупой, но всё же я её озвучу: поставил между двумя панелями TSplitter (одна панель выровнена по верху, вторая - по всему приложению), при попытке медленного перемещения ничего не происходит, но потом свершится скачок, и всё работает. Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Ччто размещено на панелях? Какой-то код в приложении присутствует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бросил на форму все так же, как было описано вами. Подобная ситуация у меня не повторилась.
Приложение что-то еще делает в этот момент?

Comment: Нет, ничего.

Comment: Несколько компиляций решило проблему, @NMD спасибо, что отозвались)